# Merging OpenGL rendering result with other graphical elements like user interface. Concepts

Tags: opengl, gui, multithreading

For my application, there are several elements drawing: An user interface elements, and several libraries for rendering part of the content of the window. Lets imagine some kind of Google Earth where a library render the earth geoid and several buttons and texts on top (possibly with transparency).

Something like that seem trivial, but it is not, cause OpenGL rendering on double-buffer at ~60fps and GUI elements are redrawn only on demand/changes for small portion of the window. One is by GPU and the other by CPU. One use a endless main loop that peek event, the other stay blocked until some event happens.

The idea is to draw the 3D elements on an internal buffer (in Thread A) and from the QT user interface (Thread B) just take the picture and put it at its correct place. Thread A and B could also have some mutex/signal to synchronize.

Questions are:

- What are the correct concepts involved? FBO? PBO? Any other?
- Where to found up-to-date information about how to implements it correctly. (meaning for example PBO with OpenGL 3+, not using ARB or deprecated stuff).
- Is this image transfer a good idea? any better solution? what about efficiency implications?

As a starting hypothesis (for simplification), I could make modification on any library/source as required.

Comment: It's relatively rare for games that involve realtime 3D elements to do selective repainting of UI. For such games, the 30-60+ fps update of the 3D scene represents the bulk of the work, so adding extra complexity to selectively repaint an overlaid UI is often deemed not worthwhile (though we may sometimes cache a few particularly dense elements) Have you tried the blunt solution of keeping all your rendering within the same frame update loop?

Comment: The 3D engine render all every frame and that is fine, but the UI is required to paint on top. The UI painting is made by CPU and is quite intensive, which would drop my frame-rate if I draw it all together in the same loop. It is also a matter of simplicity, as both libraries has also logic inside, which is updated in the same rendering loop.

Comment: My question is, have you considered NOT doing your UI painting on the CPU, but instead integrate it into your 3D engine rendering? This is exactly the kind of thing GPUs were made to accelerate by letting us offload the heavy lifting from the CPU.

Comment: Yes, that would be great, but changing all the widgets to do not use per/event mechanism, but pure real-rendering would be years of work. Also, intensive use of SVG icons, text, etc. still require CPU so I would require rendering that on a cache buffer... Just far over my schedule possibilities.